Is it possible to run Steamworks.NET on mobile devices using Mirror?
I'm currently developing a multiplayer game in Unity using Mirror and I'm facing some issues on how games are hosted. To cut costs down I'm going for a P2P model, so one person hosts the game and every one else can join the game and play as clients. As you can imagine this brings the question on what to do about NAT and connectivity issues on different networks. I'd like to use Steam for its relays but I'm not sure if the transport supports mobile builds and I can't seem to find anyone talking about it. I might just be extremely dumb and it might be obvious that the answer is no, so I apologise for that.
That being said I'd like to mention that, should it not work, I'm also interested in UDP Punching as a last resort, but then again I'm not sure how to implement that either using Mirror.

While I am not a mobile game developer, I can say that I haven't heard of Steam games for mobiles. So I would expect that it wouldn't happen. Because remember, you do need to register at Steam to create an app and publish it, not to mention to use their services (which are aimed at desktops and at most, SteamDeck and partly PS).
